# Jquery Accordion Easing

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to get a nicer feel to my drop down accordion...but it isnt happening for me...any ideas?

Here is my code in the accordion itself...

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3 id="branding"><a href="#">Branding</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>            
        <h3 id="website"><a href="#">Website</a></h3>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
    </div>
```

And in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#accordion').accordion({ navigation: true, easing: 'easeInBack' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used the 'animated' property to do this, rather than the easing plugin. e.g.:

```
 $('#some-list').accordion({collapsible: true, 
                            animated: 'bounceslide', 
                            autoHeight: false});
```

Perhaps give that a try.

Although I've realised that this uses the easing plugin anyway!

So I did a bit of research and found a comment in [this document](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/) which explains how to define your own easing-based animations. So, to do what you want, you could use the following:

```
 $.ui.accordion.animations.eib = function(settings) {
   this.slide(settings, {
     easing: "easeInBack",
     duration: 600
   });
 }      

 $(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion({
     animated: "eib"
 });
```

Comment: The top one animates it on the way down but not up...is there a way of getting both, the bit below doesnt achieve anything unfortunately.  It leaves all the accordion divs open!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's odd, it worked nicely for me using FF3. Which browser are you using?

Comment: The option was renamed into `animate` (without `d`).

Answer (score 2):

```
TypeError: $.ui.accordion.animations is undefined
```

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore.

This:

```
$(function() {    $("#accordion").accordion({
    animated: "eib"  
});
```

now has changed to animate:

```
 $(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion({
     animate: "easeOutBounce"
 });
```

Solution:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({ 
    animate: { easing: 'easeOutBounce', duration: 1000 }, 
});
```